# AWS Lambda event dict behaving in a non-standard way?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

consider the following code:

```
def handle_lambda(event, context):
    multivalue_params = event.get('multiValueQueryStringParameters', {})
    print(multivalue_params)
    print(type(multivalue_params).__name__)
    print(type(event).__name__)
```

output:

```
None
NoneType
dict
```

what gives? why doesn't the dictionary default parameter not work on the event dict? Is there a best practice that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very normal behaviour for a dict when *that keys exists*:

```
>>> event = {'multiValueQueryStringParameters': None}
>>> multivalue_params = event.get('multiValueQueryStringParameters', {})
>>> print(multivalue_params)
None
>>> print(type(multivalue_params).__name__)
NoneType
>>> print(type(event).__name__)
dict
```

`dict.get` only returns the default parameter when the key does *not exist* at all. You might want something like this:

```
# be prepared for both non-existent keys and None values:
multivalue_params = event.get('multiValueQueryStringParameters') or {}

# or expect the key to exist but to potentially be None:
multivalue_params = event['multiValueQueryStringParameters']
if multivalue_params is not None:
    # process only in this case
```